# Google App Engine JAVA: How to add more than one parameter to the Task Queue?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I wanted to use Queue tasks on my GAE application. 
I need to pass two parameters to my URL servlet runTasks. So i am doing this. 
But when I print the values for start and end it prints null for start and 15 for end. 
Am i doing anything wrong? Is this the right way to pass the parameters?

TaskOptions to = null;
to = TaskOptions.Builder.param("start", "0");
to = TaskOptions.Builder.param("end", "15");
to = to.url("/runTasks");
queue.add(to);

Thanks

Comment: queue.add(url("/path?a=b&c=d").method(Method.GET));

I am now using this to pass the parameters and it seems to be working fine. But if anyone can comment on the above process that will help.

Answer (score 3):

```
to = TaskOptions.Builder.param("start", "0").param("end", "15")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using param methods as @virsir outlines is the way forward. Putting all of the parameters in the url doesn't work if they are urlencoded. The url will be cut at the first encoded character.